# Cross domain issue on IE

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, cross-domain

I am working with a project which needs cross domain ajax. I chose cors for this purpose. It works perfectly in chrome and firefox. But in IE, the browser is not creating any ajax call.there is no console errors at all. Can anyone tell me a solution for this?

Comment: IE wont support normal ajax call for cross domain access.

Comment: You need to use XDomainRequest() for this purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For IE, you cannot use normal ajax for cross domain access. You need to use XDomainRequest() for this. 
Example:

```
xdr = new XDomainRequest();
        if (xdr) {
            xdr.onload = function () {
               alert(xdr.responseText);

            };
            xdr.open("get", url);
            xdr.send();
        }
```